# Access 2013 error 3061

Tags: sql, ms-access, multiple-tables

I have four tables in my access 2013 database. Customer, Vehicle, MonthlyPass, and Receipt. The Primary keys are CustomerID(string), VehicleiD(string) Serialnumber(autonumber), and ReceiptNo(Autonumber).
Now I want to display the fields on a form when a primary key is entered in a textbox and clicked a commandbutton. For example, when a user enter the serialnumber, I have to retrieve customer name from customer table, vehicle id from vehicle table, expiry date from monthlypass table, receiptnumber and total from the Receipt table.
 I’ve given the code below. When I run this code, the error 3061 few parameters, expected 1 occurs. I tried with and without square brackets around the fields. E.g. Vehicle.[VehicleID]  and Vehicle.VehicleID
Code:

```
Dim strSQL As String
 Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
strSQL = "SELECT Customer.[CustomerID], " & _
                "       Customer.[fName], " & _
                "       Vehicle.[VehicleID], " & _
                "       MonthlyPass.[SerialNumber], " & _
                "       MonthlyPass.[Startingdate], " & _
                "       MonthlyPass.[Expirydate], " & _
                "       MonthlyPass.[Price], " & _
                "       Receipt.[ReceiptNo], " & _
                "       Receipt.[PurchaseDate], " & _
                "       Receipt.[PayMethod], " & _
                "       Receipt.[ChequeNo], " & _
                "       Receipt.[BankName], " & _
                "       Receipt.[TotalPrice] " & _
                "FROM (Customer INNER JOIN Vehicle ON  Customer.[CustomerID]=Vehicle.[CustomerID]) " & _  
                "INNER JOIN (Receipt INNER JOIN MonthlyPass ON Receipt.[ReceiptNo] = MonthlyPass.[ReceiptNo])ON Vehicle.[VehicleID] = MonthlyPass.[VehicleID] " & _
                "WHERE (((MonthlyPass.[SerialNumber])=[forms]![frmMonthlyPass]![txtSerialNumber]));"

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Name:=strSQL, Type:=dbOpenDynaset)
```

Comment: Step through the code and stop before your "Set rs = " statement. Evaluate your strSQL variable in the immediate window using "?strSQL". Paste the query text into a new query in SQL view and execute it. Access will prompt you for the value of what it thinks is the missing parameter, so you will see what it is.

Comment: I edited the WHERE clause and it works now;
WHERE (((MonthlyPass.[SerialNumber])= " & [Forms]![frmMonthlyPass]![txtSerialNumber] & "))